# Run code when Pivot is told to refresh, but before any changes are made

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro any time a filter/slicer is changed but before the pivot table refreshes/recalculates.

I figured out a work around, but if there is a way to trigger a macro once a pivot table update is REQUESTED, I could write a much simpler code. I am aware there is an event that can be used after the pivot table is done refreshing.

I tried the following. None of them worked and won't trigger during a pivot table refresh.

- `PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges`
- `PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges`
- `PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges`

I did have these within the sheets code and not inside a module. I used the sample code from Microsoft.

Code I want to run prior to the pivot refreshing:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    CalcCol = Sheets("References").Range("B1")
    Columns(CalcCol).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Do your PivotTables have an OLAP data source?

Comment: Yes, they are. Is there anything in references I need to enable maybe?

Comment: Would you share the macro that you want to run before a filter/slicer is changed and before the pivot table refreshes/recalculates.

Comment: @EEM I added the code I want to run at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can trap it in the Worksheet_Change event, and see if there is a pivot table change included in the "Target."  If there is a change - you could undo it - then run  your code and re-do it?

I am using this method to trap changes to a slicer so I can give people the nice slicer experience instead of controls or spreadsheet drop-downs (I groan when I have to click one of those!)

My code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'trying to trap pivot table slicer changes
    
    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim si As SlicerItem
    Dim boolFoundFirstSelect As Boolean
    Dim intCountSelected As Integer, intCountNOTSelected As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sc = Target.PivotTable.Slicers(1).SlicerCache
    If Err <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Exit Sub 'leave if they are changing anything else
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'Debug.Assert 1 = 2 'Turn this on & explore the Target object to find something you can test
    For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
        If si.Selected = True Then
            intCountSelected = intCountSelected + 1
            strSelectedOption = si.Name 'this will get the LAST name ... but - in the case where there is just ONE selected, this will be useful
        Else
            intCountNOTSelected = intCountNOTSelected + 1
        End If
    Next
    'then do something ...
End Sub
```